# How to delete all the remote branch including the master branch

Tags: git, github

I want to remove all the branches of project from the Git hub, including the master branch too, in shorts i want to remove completely.

I have already seen below post
http://matthew-brett.github.io/pydagogue/gh_delete_master.html

but in above post master branch get deleted but placeholder branch get comes in to picture.

I don't want that project at all.

Comment: If you don't want the project just delete the repo?

Comment: I got the solution to delete the Project/Repo from UI as Need to Setting of the project and then Danger Zone -> Delete this repository

Answer (score 0):

Delete all remote branches:

```
$ git fetch
$ git branch -r | xargs git push origin --delete
```

- **git branch -r** returns all the remote branches.
- **git push origin --delete b1** delete a branch called 'b1'

So, using pipe we can delete all the remote branches.

Comment: `git branch -r` will include the remote prefix on the branches, while `git push origin --delete` takes the branch name as it appears at the remote. So, some filtering would be needed inbetween (for instance, `| sed 's/ *origin\///'` in the simple case). Also, `git branch -r` will show branches from many remotes if more than one exists, so depending on the situation, pushing to `origin` may or may not be enough.